# Get ids based on most popular counter

Tags: php, mysql

I am building most popular articles system where i send ID to the database and increment total_views value by 1, but i don't know how to retrieve the most popular value.

I have tried getting by value but i am new to sql and don't know what to search for.

```
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$id = '44441';


$sql = "SELECT id FROM top_pages WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   echo 'exist';
   $update = "UPDATE top_pages SET total_views = total_views + 1 where id='$id'";
   mysqli_query($conn, $update);
} else {
   echo 'not found';
   $insert = "INSERT INTO top_pages (id,total_views) VALUES ('$id', '1')";
   mysqli_query($conn, $insert);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

What i expect from the code is to pull top 10 IDs based on total_views in the past 8 hours, so only top values in the last 8 hours that are stored/updated.

Comment: i would suggest you start searching for information what SQL injection and race conditions are..

Comment: This sample code is very susceptible to SQL injection, i advice you to see this: https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/

Comment: Is OP getting downvoted because of the sql injection possibility?

Comment: i think rather then to discuss SQL injection, first of all discuss the actual issue

Comment: _“based on total_views in the past 8 hours”_ - you are only incrementing a counter here, you are not even storing any information about time - so how do you expect that to work? You need to start recording individual views including the timestamp, so that you can filter those using a WHERE clause, and then you need to count the number of those records.

Comment: *"Is OP getting downvoted because of the sql injection possibility? "* No idea as i didn't downvote @B001ᛦ most likely because he didn't provide a total reproducable example as the code is relating to MySQL data.. The topicstarter should read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for proving example data and expected results then we can stop making guesses here in the comments.

Comment: `SELECT id FROM top_pages ORDER BY total_views DESC LIMIT 10` i think u will get the top 10 from this query, but for last 8 hours u must need to read **04FS**comment

Comment: The code will not have any user input, so i need to add another column with time stamp in what format?

Comment: @RaymondNijland what part of the code is vulnerable for race conditions? thanks

Comment: *"what part of the code is vulnerable for race conditions? "* @LukeDS basically all code after `$sql = "SELECT id FROM top_pages WHERE id='$id'";` is possibly prone to race conditions but without table structure like i already requested we can't rule race conditions out that's why the warnings about race condition.

Comment: @devpro

I have added a column that will store timestamp of the new entry, can you tell me what would the query look like for the last 8 hours? Thanks

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks, just asked because its the first time hearing about ```race condition``` so not sure extcly what to look for here

Comment: *"just asked because its the first time hearing about race condition so not sure extcly what to look for here"* @LukeDS  in that case i would suggest looking on [owasp](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Testing_Guide_v3_Table_of_Contents) in general to find (possibly) other vulnerabilities you might never heard of before.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the date column, you can get the data from last 8 hours as like:

```
SELECT id FROM top_pages 
WHERE your_date_column_name > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -8 HOUR)
ORDER BY total_views DESC LIMIT 10
```

Using `INTERVAL -8 HOUR` to get 8 hour old data

`ORDER BY total_views DESC` to get highest views record

`LIMIT 10` to limited record

Comment: don't know if it matters for the topicstarter but `ORDER BY total_views DESC` can still cause non deterministic (random) order in the resultset in cases off "ties" within the `total_views` column.

Comment: hmm @RaymondNijland your point is valid, maybe OP get thinking about the FIFO in last 8 hours

Comment: I dont know if i was explanatory enough sorry for that, i plan to display most popular read articles that were published in the last 8 hours top 10 in order of most read one top to bottom.

this is time column i created:

https://i.imgur.com/XfyJO0Z.png

Comment: *"your point is valid, maybe OP get thinking about the FIFO in last 8 hours"* indeed topicstarter if you want/need to have a pure 100% deterministic (fixed) result always you can use multicolumn ordering like `ORDER BY total_views, id` but the second column must have unique values best is to use a column with a primary or unique key but using a `datetime(6)` datatype would most likely also be fine.

Comment: @magix01: u are using `total_views` column for most popular right, for suppose u got 12 records in last 8 hours, all of them having 10 views each, in this case, which 10 records you need? do you want to use First in First out option by using time column or primary key column?

Comment: @devpro

I don't think that is important, since there are a lot of reading going on so chance of 2 or more articles to have same count number is slim chance.

@ Raymond Nijland

I am new to SQL so what code exactly do you mean could produce SQL injection, what if there is user input and i filter it to allow only numbers since i only store numbers in db, like:

    $id = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_GET['postid']);

Comment: @devpro

But if i insert only int variable in database and strip everything else theoretically there should be no problems? Also thank you for helping me.

Comment: @magix01: maybe , but i said good option... glad to help u friend.

Answer (score 0):

Your current way of representing data will not help you, because you have no information whatsoever about when `total_views` was updated. Let's assume that a `top_pages` entry was created 30 days ago and has a total_views of 3000. There is no way to determine how many of these 3000 were done in the last 8 hours.

Instead, it is much better to have a table like this:

> visits(id, page_id, visit_timestamp)

and then do this

```
select page_id, count(*)
from visits
group by page_id
where visit_timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR)
order by count(*) desc
limit 0, 10;
```

Comment: I already created timestamp, i am more interested on how to make this code sql injection proof, since i am new to sql. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @magix01 your question was not about SQL injection, hence my answer is not about that either, but in this comment I will brief you into the right direction. First of all, if the id in your query is not a user input at any point, then your code, as it is is not vulnerable to SQL injection. However, it's never too early to start writing parameterized queries, in the case of PHP that would mean the usage of PDO. Read this tutorial carefully: http://zetcode.com/php/pdo/